# How to match a value in one column to another column based on hierarchy level

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have a table that contains 4 columns: `entry_id, NAME, type, upper_id`.

[image]

Each `entry_id` corresponds to a specific `upper_id`. There can be many different entry_id's that correspond to SAME upper_id. The column `type` represent the level of that entry in terms of hierarchy.

```
1 --> First level
2 --> Second level
3 --> Third level
```

I need to match what is in the `upper_id` to the `entry_id` in order to add another column for `upper_name` which will be found in the same table column `name`. In the example above, if `upper_id = '1001'` for an `entry_id`, I need to find this value in the `entry_id` and grab the name found.

An `entry_id` with `type = '1'` will always have an `upper_id` that has a value in the `entry_id` with a `type = '2'`. And an `entry_id` with a `type = '2'` will always have an upper id that has a value in `entry_id` with a `type = '3'`. An `entry_id` with type = '3' will never have an `upper_id`, and its `upper_name` column will be `NULL`.

The results will  look like this:

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_1
(     ENTRY_ID int,
      NAME string,
      TYPE int,
      UPPER_ID int
);

INSERT INTO TBL_1
values
(1234,'bichon',1,'1001'),
(1124,'yorkie',1,'1001'),
(1009,'golden',1,'1001'),
(6722,'poodle',1,'1001'),
(1001,'canine',2,'2002'),
(2002,'animal',3,NULL)
```

Do you know how I can formulate a query that allows me to include an "`upper_name`" column from the data already in the table?

Answer (score 1):

left join the table with itself as following:

```
select 
t1.ENTRY_ID ,
t1.NAME,
t1.TYPE,
t1.UPPER_ID,
t2.NAME as upper_name

from TBL_1 as t1
left join TBL_1 as t2 on t1.UPPER_ID = t2.ENTRY_ID
```

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all records from the left table (`t1`), and the matching records from the right table (`t2`),in case no matching record from the right table it will return `null` for its selected columns. [image]

Comment: I assume someone down voted you because you didn't have the `AND t1.type +1 = t2.type` on the `ON` clause

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim I think it is not required to be added since the data consistent and data integrity is applied

Comment: I don't disagree, "with the example data given" the requirement seems completely unneeded.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You're right, it is not required

Answer (score 1):

LEFT JOIN is the key.

```
WITH table_data (ENTRY_ID, NAME, TYPE, UPPER_ID) AS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM values
    (1234,'bichon',1,1001),
    (1124,'yorkie',1,1001),
    (1009,'golden',1,1001),
    (6722,'poodle',1,1001),
    (1001,'canine',2,2002),
    (2002,'animal',3,NULL)
)
SELECT t1.*,
    t2.name as upper_name
FROM table_data AS t1
LEFT JOIN table_data AS t2
    ON t1.UPPER_ID = t2.ENTRY_ID
        AND t1.type +1 = t2.type
```

gives:

| ENTRY_ID | NAME | TYPE | UPPER_ID | UPPER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | bichon | 1 | 1001 | canine |
| 1124 | yorkie | 1 | 1001 | canine |
| 1009 | golden | 1 | 1001 | canine |
| 6722 | poodle | 1 | 1001 | canine |
| 1001 | canine | 2 | 2002 | animal |
| 2002 | animal | 3 |  |  |

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you know how I can take into account if I don't hav the TYPE in ordered sequence? So instead of 1->2->3, it is 1->3->2? I should have the same results as above, but 2 and 3 are switched.

Answer (score 0):

Join the table to itself on upper_id = entry_id and type = type - 1, then union all with the type 3 rows.

```
SELECT x.*, y.NAME as upper_name
FROM tbl_1 x
    inner join tbl_1 y on x.UPPER_ID = y.ENTRY_ID and x.TYPE = y.TYPE - 1
WHERE x.TYPE IN (1,2)
UNION ALL
SELECT *, NULL AS upper_name
FROM TBL_1
WHERE type = 3;
```